# Azure ML Multiclass Classification output

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using a Multiclass Classification: News categorization example from azure ML and trying to setup a simple predictive web service that should get article as parameter and return me scored label to which category the input article text belongs, however doesn't meter what I tried it always require 2 parameters : ID , Text , and when I'm passing a new ID that was not existed in training , it gives me error that there is no rows in dataset, my question is how it suppose to work , what I'm missing here?

https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Multiclass-Classification-News-categorization-2

Answer (score 1):

See the following web service. You basically need to trim ID off as it is the label column, and it is NOT needed when scoring new data.

http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Multiclass-Classification-News-categorization-Web-Service-1